# How to Pass windows full title name with space using Pywinauto in python

Tags: python

I wanted to automate Adobe Reader menus,

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.start_(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe")
```

so after how to get complete windows title "Adobe Reader" & navigate to File menus

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation: http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html

You can use [`MenuItems()`](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.HwndWrapper.HwndWrapper.MenuItems) to retrieve the menu items of a Dialog